# Call a Class file inside App_code folder using usercontrol page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to to call a class inside `App_code folder` using `Usercontrol` page how to do it?

```
namespace Project.Folder
{
     public partial class DefaultMenu2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
     {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Util.Function();/*this is what i wan to call but cannot call it in my project */
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: check the namespace in app_code class and try to put that when you calling it...or provide a sample of your app_code class

Answer (score 0):

> It's because the function is not static.

Your current situation is like below.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void abc()
    {
    }
}
```

In  this case, In order to call `abc() function`, the class need to be `Instantiated` first. Then the object will provide the function `Accessibility`.

Example

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.abc();
```

---

You can also change the function

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void abc()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `static function` without `class instantiation`.

```
Class1.abc();
```